# Como fazer o modal pegar valores do foreach com Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Preciso fazer o modal mostrar o valor do item que for selecionado no foreach, porem ele só está pegando o último valor.
Segue o código:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    @csrf
    <!--Listagem-->
    <h2>Tipos de Produtos</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary create-tipoproduto">Adicionar</button>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-sm-1">ID</th>
                <th class="col-sm-6">Descrição</th>
                <th class="col-sm-1">Inflável</th>
                <th class="col-sm-2">Ações</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($tiposprodutos as $tipoproduto)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $tipoproduto->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $tipoproduto->descricao }}</td>
                <td>{{ $tipoproduto->inflavel }}</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary remove-tipoproduto"></button></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--Dialog Excluir-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="dialog-form-excluir" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Excluir Tipo de Produto</h5>
                </div>

                <form id="form-excluir" action="{{  route('excluir_tipoproduto', ['id' => $tipoproduto->id]) }}" method="POST">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @csrf
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="desc">Descrição</label>
                                <input class="form-control text-input" type="text" name="descricao" id="descricao" value="<?php echo $tipoproduto['descricao']?>" disabled>
                                <label for="infl">Inflável?</label>
                                <input class="form-control text-input" type="text" name="inflavel" id="inflavel" value=<?php echo $tipoproduto['inflavel']?> disabled>
                            </fieldset>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-fade">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="botaoExcluir" name="botaoExcluir">Excluir</button>
                      </div>
                </form>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vai ter que trabalhar com Javascript, o botão de clicar na linha do produto deverá chamar uma função JS que passe os dados do produto à tela modal e configure o botão de confirmar exclusão dela, o qual deverá chamar um script do lado servidor, passando o código do produto

Answer (score 0):

Você pode recuperar os dados corretos realizando uma requisição com ajax ao backend e configurar os inputs do modal a partir do retorno dela.

Com o atributo [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) na tag **button**, quando clicado, ele chamara a função que configurará os inputs ao mesmo tempo que abre o modal.